# Why does the initial blockchain download get stuck part way through?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

I am trying to get Bitcoin up and running on a fairly underpowered laptop and Windows Vista using `Bitcoin-Qt 0.5.0.1`. After installing and starting the program, I am stuck at at the syncing stage at 92150 blocks and 0%, and have been for several hours. What could I try to get the program working?

Comment: Try restarting the OS.

Comment: also try getting the latest release, 0.5.2. can't hurt.

Comment: I am in the same boat except my wallet is up to date and 7.1.0. Im on ubuntux64 and the wallet wont even start the sync with 8 connections on the BC network. The process is not throwing any errors and the machine I'm on is fully functional. I have cleaned the bitcoin directory twice and rebooted twice as well. I am connected to the Internet as I am still trying to connect as I type this. As of right now after running for several hours, sync is at 0 of 207028 blocks with 8 connections.

Comment: closely related: [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/5406)

Answer (score 3):

Restart OS, restart Bitcoin, try forwarding port 8333 on your router to your machine.  If there is no progress after that, you might consider deleting all the files in your [Bitcoin data folder](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) **except wallet.dat** (if you have made any transactions, deleting `wallet.dat` will make you lose your Bitcoins). If you just want to use Bitcoins casually, or don't want to wait for the client to sync, you can consider using an [eWallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:EWallets).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin connects to random nodes by default (home connections too)

To get a fst download you need high bandwidth nodes.

Edit the bitocin.config as described there: [What is the fastest possible way to download the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12001/what-is-the-fastest-possible-way-to-download-the-blockchain)