# What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization, canonical-question

I hadn't started/used my Bitcoin client for ages. Now, whenever I start the client, it is downloading `block 135407` and does **not** progress past it.

What can I do?

Comment: See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/ for some things to try.

Comment: What version of the client?

Comment: thanks. I did try things mentioned in the other answers. I posted an answer to this question. @StephenGornick: I am using the latest 0.5.2 client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this happen to me once. It was apparently caused by an incompatible peer node.

1. Delete `$HOME/.bitcoin/peers.dat`
2. Restart `bitcoind`

Afterwards, new compatible peers will be found, and hopefully, you'll start processing blocks as expected again.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, based on the comments I have tried a couple of things but in the end only the following worked:

1. Close Bitcoin client
2. Backup files from %APPDATA%\Bitcoin
3. Optional:Download Block chains from:     http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/ to prevent lengthy initial download **(Warning: the link advises against doing this if you have transactions in your wallet).**
4. Start Bitcoin client with the
   `-rescan` option from command line.

After that the client started downloading blockchains again. This worked for me. Not sure if this will work for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but the ***-rescan*** option didn’t help.

In my case, there were a lot of lines referring to orphan blocks in my *debug.log* file (not 100 % sure it’s related but it may):

```
2014-08-18 20:52:57 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 0, prev=00000000000000001132f6ac32387e51960e3154b2ad4420bdeb64d77999388f
2014-08-18 20:54:00 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 1, prev=00000000000000000e9926124cabed78be0ae8bab22fb20acc643e94749120f8
2014-08-18 20:56:37 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 2, prev=00000000000000001b3f790fc107051c17702d305b08a3ae6325f40ecf44eae9
...
```

Finally, I tried to restart the client with the ***-reindex*** option which fixed my problem (but took 100 % of my CPU usage for several hours while reprocessing the blockchain).

So if the rescan option don’t work, don’t give up, try the reindex option!

Answer (score -1):

You should update your bitcoin software.
Old bitcoin versions are not supported.

Look here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55852.0

Comment: It's true that regularly upgrading is encouraged, but all clients since 0.2.10 have supported to switch that happened on Februari 20th.