# Bitcoin client 0.4.1.1 stuck at block 176947

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Bitcoin client stuck. Tried to rebuild whole blockchain, but it went up to that number and got stuck again.

Here's a screenshot: http://vvcap.net/db/2IR75OWyJj5AsUW7eo_i.htp

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate: [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/5406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded version 4.4.1.1 to try to reproduce your problem, but couldn't.  Here's the beginning, and relevant mid-section of the debug.log file when I ran it on a machine which I hadn't used for a month or so:

```
Bitcoin version 0.4.1.1-beta
Default data directory /home/user/.bitcoin
Bound to port 8333
Loading addresses...
dbenv.open strLogDir=/home/user/.bitcoin/database strErrorFile=/home/user/.bitcoin/db.log
Loaded 19026 addresses
 addresses              1337ms
Loading block index...
LoadBlockIndex(): hashBestChain=000000000000052e27b6  height=173760
 block index           13603ms
Loading wallet...
[...]
SetBestChain: new best=0000000000000959beb5  height=176945  work=302325188992488282894
SetBestChain: new best=000000000000011c616f  height=176946  work=302331966182716897933
SetBestChain: new best=000000000000052c233f  height=176947  work=302338743372945512972
SetBestChain: new best=00000000000002c5eaa8  height=176948  work=302345520563174128011
SetBestChain: new best=000000000000089bf6dd  height=176949  work=302352297753402743050
```

Maybe you could show us yours?  I tend to agree with Stephen that it's likely a disk space problem.

Comment: Yes... good idea. Why didn't I start with logging myself. Unfortunately I got logs shoved away. Let me try to reproduce it now, and I will share logs. I'm pretty certain it will lock up on that block, it was happening yesterday all day from multiple workstations. It's definitely not a space problem, but no idea how could I not think of examining log

Comment: It looks very stupid, but I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Thanks for idea to look @ log, I guess this is as much as it gets at this point

Answer (score 0):

The blockchain chews up well over a gigabyte of disk space.  Are you running out of disk space?

Comment: 'Well over a gigabyte' sounds like the understatement of the year, lol.