# Bitcoin client only has 1 connection?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization, connection

I have had bitcoin for a little bit now.  It has been going very smoothly.  I have set up 3 accounts for various activities, privacy, and security reasons.  I now can not get all of the block chain.  When I go to download more of the block chain it just sits at 175408.  I have been at it for hours.  When I first got bitcoin it worked perfectly, but now even after reinstalling the bas**** it is still stuck there, and my total connections went from eight to a one.  If anybody has any suggestions on to what the problem could be I would be grateful.

Comment: Accounts?  What do you mean by "accounts".  If you are referring to Windows user accounts, and each one has a copy of the blockchain, are you running out of disk space then maybe?

Comment: What o/s, o/s versioin, and Bitcoin client version?

Comment: Voted to close (ambiguous question) since the author has not followed up with answers to important questions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the client is having a hard time finding peers.  If you close it and remove the addr.dat then restart, it will go through the dnsseed process again.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a few times before:

- [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/659)
- [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/659)
- [Bitcoin client 0.4.1.1 stuck at block 176947](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3486/659)

Is there anything in the answers of those that helps?