# Repeated error synchronizing Bitcoin client

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I've tried unsuccessfully 2 times to download the application from this site https://www.weusecoins.com/en/getting-started. Last failure stopped at around 16,000 blocks. I am trying to get setup with a wallet and begin buying BTC's. I do not want to use an online wallet service.

The only other applications that I had open during the download was Firefox and I use AVG Free Antivirus, but do not know how to disable it. I have restarted the OS.

What to do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the failure you're seeing? Does it just stop, or do you see an error?

Comment: Also, which operating system (version) and which version of the Bitcoin client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/5406)

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is overclocked, this may fail repeatedly. Even overclocks that are stable in other situations can fail during this CPU/memory intensive sync process. Go back to stock settings and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck if you just use a bootstrap file. [Download one](http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/bootstrap.dat) and put it in your bitcoin data directory (remove everything else from the directory, but let `wallet.dat` stay). Name the file `bootstrap.dat` and then start the client.

The bootstrap file I linked to only contains 190.000 blocks, so after that you still need to download ~40.000 blocks.

Also, as Abei Villafane said, be careful with overclocking. It only takes a single memory error for the chain download to break, and those are far less likely when not overclocking.