# Bitcoin Core extremely high syncing time

Tags: transactions, wallet, synchronization

I'm running Bitcoin Core wallet on a gaming PC with a GTX 750ti, and 3.7ghz quadcore processor, and 16gb of ram. My internet download speed is 15 116mbps via hardwire.

But for some reason the syncing is stuck on 2 years and 33 weeks. I just ordered 100$ worth of bitcoin (which should come in 7 days) and I'm worried that it won't go through if it's still syncing.

Does anyone know what I could do to fix this? It's making me anxious.

Comment: What does the `debug.log` say? Have you tried starting with `-rescan`? Possible duplicate of [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/5406)

Answer (score 2):

The transaction will go through whether Bitcoin Core is done syncing or not, so don't worry about that.  You just won't see the transaction appear in the application until syncing is finished.

The Bitcoin Core GUI doesn't always give the most accurate updates on its progress.  But one way to check the progress is to open Help:Debug Window, click the Console tab, and type `getinfo`.  Look at the `blocks` number.  Then try `getinfo` again a minute or two later and see if the `blocks` number has increased.  If so, you are in fact syncing and just have to be patient.  Note that you are downloading about 60 GB of data and performing fairly intensive computations on all of it.

If you get tired of waiting, you might prefer a "thin" client that doesn't try to download and verify the entire block chain.  See [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/cannot-access-my-bitcoins-because-my-wallet-is-still-synchronising-what-can-i-d) to learn about your options for switching.

Comment: I thought I was stuck on 2 years 33 weeks as well, but it just reduced by a week :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but I just want to announce that I've been able to reduce the sync time from 12 days to 7 hours by disabling Windows Defender.

If you do not use Windows Defender then you can use the Task Manager for debugging. Use it to see if another application start using a large part of your CPU resources when starting the Bitcoin Core application.

**You must enable antivirus when sync is complete.**

But Nate Eldredge's answer is still a good answer if you do not want to ride with the antivirus program.

Answer (score 0):

modern core can fully synchronize in about 24 hours. it displays funds only when the synchronization catches up to the time when you recieved the funds

Answer (score 0):

I'd add, that after you have a full sync, it's not a bad idea to throw your entire Core folder; including all the blockchain data, in exact form, onto an external HDD.

I've had a number of instances where a bad shutdown causes Bitcoin Core to throw errors on startup after reboot, thus having to re-sync the entire blockchain.

Having a large portion local, you can restore from there, without having to redownload the entire chain.