# Blockchain download stuck on Bitcoin core wallet

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, client, synchronization, windows

The caching up process was progressing (slowly but still progressing) until it got stuck after processing 436820 blocks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8h0z.png

3 days after, I'm still at 70.76%

Says I'm connected though (to 8 peers)

Any clue?
(debug.log: https://pastebin.com/QSaUY2gm)

Comment: Can you post the `debug.log` file?

Comment: related: [What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2979/5406)

Comment: That's very weird. Your peers are syncronized; there's no error suggesting that your node rejected a block; and it was open for 2 minutes without validating any more blocks.