# Stuck on blockchain 8791 - Synchronizing

Tags: blockchain

I don't know what's wrong with it, but I would really appreciate it if someone can help me. I've already been receiving money from this address so I really don't want to delete it. I have 3 BTC coming in.

Comment: Do you have any connections to other peers?  You can see that by mousing over the bars at the bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 1):

You should [backup](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet#Securing_the_Bitcoin-QT_or_bitcoind_wallet) and secure/encrypt your wallet before messing with anything. If you have a second computer, I'd recommend getting the software working there and ensure that your wallet works on that computer.

If you're running an older version of Bitcoin-Qt, upgrade to [0.8.1](http://bitcoin.org/en/download) or later.

Check out [this other question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/why-does-the-initial-blockchain-download-get-stuck-part-way-through?rq=1) after that.